# How to turn sugar syrup into sugaring wax?

Tags: sugar

I would like to know how I can make sugar syrup of 1-2 tar consistency and when it cools, it is neither crystallized nor too thin syrup?

What quantity of citric acid or liquid glucose should I use in 1KG of sugar? How much water?

I have tried at least 5 times, but the result is either crystallized or too thin. I need a syrup which is sticky, so as to be used as wax as well.

Comment: If I understand correctly, 1 tar is just syrup and 2 tar is soft ball (going by http://www.mamtaskitchen.com/recipe_display.php?id=13000) - the two are different. Which are you trying to achieve? (Sounds more like soft ball, or maybe a bit short of it.) Do you have a candy thermometer? This is about temperatures, not just quantities.

Comment: Are you talking about this kind of "sugaring wax"?  http://tipnut.com/body-sugaring/

Answer (score 1):

I think if you start with regular sugar syrup, you have too much liquid. I make sugaring wax by putting 8 parts sugar, 1 part water and 1 part lemon juice in a sauce pan and let that simmer for about 10-15 minutes until you have an amber colour.

It will take a couple of times to judge the mixture on thickness and colour. Once it's set, you should be able to push a finger in it and that mark should stay there for a couple of minutes.

If your mixture is too pale, it's going to be too liquid and the finger mark will disappear too quickly. You can just put it back on the stove and let it boil for a bit longer.
If your mixture is too dark, it's going to be too hard. You will be able to make the finger mark, but it's gonna be hard to do. You can reheat the mixture in the microwave and use it warm.

Depending on how you want to use it, cooking times are more or less forgiving.

Comment: can u simplyfy 10-15 minutes time thing becoz with more quantity of wax, we need to observe other features as colour, texture, stirring, ratio and at best temperature. pls elaborate